# Avoiding Overfitting by making Parameters Sum to 0

Tags: optimization, overfitting

I'm following a blog that is modelling soccer scores using a parameterised poisson process. Each team has an attack rating $\alpha_{i}$ and defence rating $\beta_{i}$.

When coding up the model and optimising the parameters, the [blog](https://www.robert-hickman.eu/post/dixon_coles_1/) does as so:

[image]

My question is this: why does forcing the parameters to sum to nought make the model more generalised ?